# Finite set as intersection of two (or more) infinite sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I stumbled upon an interesting question and I can't seem to find the answer, although it seems easy.
So, if we have an **infinite** set $X$ and a **finite** subset $A \subseteq X$ can we find two (or more) *infinite* subsets $A_1, A_2 \subset X$ such that $A=A_1 \cap A_2$? In either case, can you provide a proof sketch or a counterexample? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is because any infinite set can be partitioned into two infinite subsets. So given such an $X$ and $A$, let $Y_1\sqcup Y_2$ be a partition of $X\setminus A$ into disjoint infinite sets, and let $A_1=Y_1\cup A, A_2=Y_2\cup A$.

This proof, however, uses the axiom of choice. Without the axiom of choice, we can have infinite sets which cannot be paritioned into two disjoint infinite subsets; these are called [**amorphous sets**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set).

To prove (using choice) that you can always partition an infinite set into two disjoint infinite subsets, the most direct approach is via [**Zorn's lemma**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma). Let $X$ be a fixed infinite set, and let $\mathbb{P}$ be the poset whose elements are pairs $(p, q)$ with

- $p, q$ disjoint subsets of $X$, and
- either $p$ and $q$ are both infinite, or they are both finite and have the same cardinality;

we order $\mathbb{P}$ by $$(p, q)\ge (p', q')\iff p\supseteq p'\mbox{ and } q\supseteq q'.$$ It's not hard to show that every chain in $\mathbb{P}$ has an upper bound (HINT: take unions), so by Zorn $\mathbb{P}$ has a maximal element $(p, q)$; but since $X$ is infinite, we can't have $p, q$ finite (if we did, since $X$ is infinite $X\setminus(p\cup q)$ is also infinite; let $x, y\in X\setminus(p\cup q)$, and consider $(p\cup\{x\}, q\cup\{y\})$), so $p$ and $q$ are infinite subsets of $X$. It's then easy to show that $X=p\sqcup q$, so we're done.

Comment: Thank you so much, I felt it was easy, but I had no idea that we can imply such thing. I try not to use the AC, so I was thinking of constructive proofs. In an amorphous set, are there cases that my question has a negative answer?

Comment: @SotirisSimos Sure. Take $X$ amorphous, and $A$ any finite subset of $X$ (including $\emptyset$!). There are no infinite $A_1, A_2\subseteq X$ with $A_1\cap A_2=A$. Why? Well, every subset of an amorphous set is either finite or cofinite (exercise); since $A_1$ and $A_2$ are infinite, they  must be cofinite. So $X\setminus (A_1\cap A_2)$ is finite - in particular, $A_1\cap A_2$ is infinite!